# Using phrases in email to prof (academic)

Tags: grammar, british-english, past-tense, email, academia

**1. "I hope you are doing well"**

Will be it polite, if I write it in an email to Proff/start an email with it?
He was ill, and we wrote me about it

**2. Thank you for taking time from your busy schedule to meet with me**

How to use this sentense in past tense?

**3. I am writing you to let know, that ...**

"to let know", is it polite? I woul like to write about what I have decoded according to Proff' suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Yes, that's OK, or "I hope you are feeling better".

(2) That's OK too even if the meeting was in the past.

(3) Nothing impolite about it, but it needs to be *to let you know that....*